# Kotlin also block not running after Flow collect

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to run some code after my Flow has completed fetching it from my Room database.  I have a list of Jobs, and then I want to create another list of the Jobs that have the current user as a Worker (as in someone hired for the job).  Here is my code

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.getAllJobsFlow().collect {
                jobsDataList = it
                jobsListUpdateDatabase.postValue(it)
            }.also {
                appliedAndAcceptedDataList =  jobsDataList.filter { it ->
                    it.workers.any {
                        it.worker_id.equals(PosterPalApplication.USER_ID)
                    }
                }
            }
            appliedAndAcceptedDataList.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "job title = ${it.job.title} with worker")
            }
```

I don't care what thread the also block runs on but would be better to run off UI Thread.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I also noticed another issue, the collect block runs multiple times, same behaviour with collect latest.  My guess is I should be using some sort of transformation or something like that

Comment: That's what `collect` does. That's what a flow is for. It emits a new value every time the Room database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is most likely infinite, so `collect` will never completes.
You can use `onEach` to run you code:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.getAllJobsFlow()
        .onEach{ dataList ->
            appliedAndAcceptedDataList =  dataList.filter { it ->
                it.workers.any {
                    it.worker_id.equals(PosterPalApplication.USER_ID)
                }
            }
        }
        .collect {
            jobsDataList = it
            jobsListUpdateDatabase.postValue(it)
        }
    //unreachable code
    appliedAndAcceptedDataList.forEach {
        Log.d(TAG, "job title = ${it.job.title} with worker")
    }
```

But something tells me that you do not need additional functions at all, you can put all the code in `collect` block and everything will work exactly as you need.

Comment: I think I had the same problem with onEach but I will try your implementation.   This is coming from Room so there aren’t too many options.   Can I convert the flow into another type?

Comment: Flows from Room are infinite., so it depends what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to refilter this list every time the flow emits (which happens each time the database is modified)? Or only the first time it emits?

Comment: @bylazy, you're still running some code after `collect` that will never be reached.

Comment: First question is why does the last forEach statement never get called?  I assumed it would just run on the UI thread, which also isn't right, but that is what I would expect to happen.  I call the function the code is in from my viewmodel init block.  I want it to fetch all of the jobs from the database in one shot and then I deliver them to my adapter using LiveData.  Then in the future if there is ever anything inserted into the database I would expect that the flow would trigger again.

Comment: Another question, would LiveData not have the same problem?  Or would there be another issue where it would only update when it is explicitly called?  The best behaviour would be to treat the list as a single emission and then let the coder decide what to do with it!

Comment: Just try to put everything into `collect` block and check if it is works. As far as I can see it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had made a simple mistake.  In another thread I was loading fixture data so I moved this block of code to an invocationComplete and it stopped triggering multiple times.  Thank you for everyone’s input!

Answer (score 0):

`flow.collect{ }` is a suspending function, it needs to be executed within a coroutine. It takes a lambda as a parameter that is called on every new value. **Since it's a suspend function, the coroutine that calls collect may suspend until the flow is closed**, and like your flow is not closed so all code coming after collect is never reached